# Ubuntu on Asus F201E

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot, asus, uefi

My grandpa just bought a new netbook, the Asus f201e, shipped with Windows 8 :( After 5 minutes he said "I don't want this crap" and so I ow try to install Ubuntu 12.10 64bit there. Have the iso copied (Unetbootin) on my stick and booted, got the dialog wether to install or try ubuntu. No matter what I choose, i just get a black screen and nothing happens.

I deactivated FastBoot in Bios but still used (U)EFI as my grandpa wants the ability to run both.

What do i have to do?

Isn't the F201E sometimes shipped with Ubuntu? How comes i can't install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have hit [bug #1132683](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1132683). This model is certified to run a pre-installed image, however see [this question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/220675), there may be issues with stock Ubuntu on this particular hardware.

Comment: Thanks, you know any way to get the pre-installed image? Couldn't find it...

Comment: I don't know, can't tell from [Asus repositories](http://asus.archive.canonical.com/) on Canonical. Did you try booting 13.04? The reporter of [bug 1157435](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/1157435) says it works great on this model.