# Windows 8 Problem, liveusb, bios = blackscreen

Tags: installation, boot, uefi

I bought a new laptop (Asus x201) and I wanted to install Ubuntu as a Dual boot or just Ubuntu (so delete Win8), and there are everywhere problems. It started that while booting Win 8 I cannot even access the bios menu. After researching there is only a so called "UEFI". 
I need to access the BIOS so I can use my external DVD drive for the Ubuntu or other linux CDs/DVD, but somehow it did not work

I did some more research and find out that Win 8 does not suppport Ubuntu installer so I uninstalled windows and wiped the hard drive. As my external DvD drive is not working I followed the instruction to make a Liveusb.

I can access it while booting ad4 options are given

> Try Ubuntu
>   INstall Ubuntu
>   OEM install
>   Check disc for defect

I tried all of them but nothing works. When I choose one of the 4 option nothing happens, just a black screen. I also can access the gnu grub but I don't know what to do!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu on Asus F201E](http://askubuntu.com/questions/279640/ubuntu-on-asus-f201e)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the bios during boot with F2.

You must install Ubuntu secure 64 for EFI system http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-secure/